# app (use Google cardboard SDK) has been rejected. What should i do now?

Tags: ios, google-cardboard, google-vr

As i described at [link](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/121)

````
Our app (use Google cardboard SDK) has been rejected by following issue: 

```
Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

imageWithName:

The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
```

(Same with https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/issues/296 ??)

```
/xxxxx/xxxxxx   develop  grep -r imageWithName .
Binary file ./xxxxxxx.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/xxxxxxxxxxx.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches
Binary file ./Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libCardboardSDK_arm64.a matches
Binary file ./Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libCardboardSDK_armv7.a matches
Binary file ./Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libCardboardSDK_i386.a matches
Binary file ./Pods/GVRSDK/Libraries/libCardboardSDK_x86_64.a matches
```
````

What should i do to get my app approved ?

Comment: Wow, I've used imageWithName hundreds of times.

Comment: @BenClayton i think you used imageName, the method of Apple, not imageWithName, method in Google cardboard SDK.

Comment: @Dinh Nhat: you have no solution for fixing it without Google supporting. You should report to Google and wait them fix it.

Comment: @nynohu You're right! Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imageWithName` method is removed (changed to `imageWithName:color:`) at Google cardboard SDK v1.0.0.

For detail see [the link](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-ios-sdk/issues/121#event-823330874)